# Is there a metric on the extended reals which yields regular and infinite limits?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

The question is in the title:

> Is there a (extended) metric on the extended reals which yields
>   regular and infinite limits?

but in particular I want know the explicit construction of said metric.

Of course, by "yields regular and infinite limits" I mean: Let $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$. The (extended) metric on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is so that: Given a sequence $a : \mathbb{N} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ , with only real numbers in its image, we have:
$$\lim a = a_\infty \in \mathbb{R}\Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon > 0 : \exists N\in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n\geq N : |a_\infty - a_n| < \epsilon$$
$$\lim a = \infty \Leftrightarrow \forall c > 0 : \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n\geq N : a_n > c$$
$$\lim a = -\infty \Leftrightarrow \forall c > 0 : \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n\geq N : a_n < c$$

Here $\lim a$ refers to he limit in the aforementioned metric space.

This is hinted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1418481/166694), but I still do not know how to find the metric in question.

Comment: It doesn't extend the usual metric, but you can take a homeomorphism with $[-1,1]$ and use the resulting metric. This preserves the topology and hence limits.

Comment: @Matt Samuel How do I get the explicit metric from this?

Comment: Use an explicit homeomorphism, say $x\mapsto x/(1+x)$, then $d(x,y)=|x/(1+x)-y/(1+y)|$.

Comment: Actually $x/(1+|x|)$ would be a better choice because the other one isn't a homeomorphism.

Comment: @MattSamuel This may be a dumb question: How do you evaluate the metric at say $(\infty, x)$ for some $x$? (How do you deal with $\pm \infty$?)

Comment: The only way to define it and have it be continuous is to take the limit as it approaches these extended numbers. The limits exist.

Comment: In Matt Samuel's metric,$ d(x,\pm \infty)=|x/(1+|x|)\mp 1|$ and $d(-\infty,\infty)=2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hinted in your link, there is a bijection $f:\overline{\Bbb R} \to \left[-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2\right]$ given by $$f(x)=\begin {cases} -\frac \pi 2 & x=-\infty\\\arctan x & -\infty \lt x \lt \infty \\\frac \pi 2 & x=+\infty \end {cases}$$  Now your metric on $\overline{\Bbb R}$ is $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$

Comment: Let me add that, somewhat importantly, this map induces a _homeomorphism_ between $(-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$ and $\mathbb R$. This ensures that the convergence behavior we induce by this metric on $\mathbb R$ is indeed the same as the one provided by the usual metric. Also, a small argument is needed to justify that „converging to ∞“ in the sense of this metric is precisely the same as divergence to infinity (which is a good exercise if it's not immediately clear).