# Equivalent Lebesgue integrability

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, bochner-spaces

I'm reading section "Integration of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued functions" on page 103 from Amann's texbook *Analysis III*.

> The decomposition of an $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued function into its positive and negative parts allows us also to extend the Lebesgue integral to measurable $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued functions admitting negative values. We say that $f \in \mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$ is **Lebesgue integrable with respect to ${\mu}$** if $\int_{X} f^{+} d \mu<\infty$ and $\int_{X} f^{-} d \mu<\infty$. In this case,
> $$
> \int_{X} f d \mu:=\int_{X} f^{+} d \mu-\int_{X} f^{-} d \mu
> $$
> is called the **(Lebesgue) integral over $X$ with respect to the measure $\mu$**.
>
> **3.11 Remarks:** For $f \in \mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, \overline{\mathbb{R}})$, these three statements are equivalent:
>
> - (i) $f$ is Lebesgue integrable with respect to $\mu$.
> - (ii) $\int_{X}|f| d \mu<\infty$;
> - (iii) There exists $g \in \mathcal{L}_{1}(X, \mu, \mathbb{R})$ such that $|f| \leq g \mu$-a.e.
>
> **Proof:**
>
> "(i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)" This is a consequence of $|f|=f^{+}+f^{-}$.
>
> "(ii) $\Rightarrow$ (iii)" **Theorem $3.9$** says that $|f| \in \mathcal{L}_{1}(X, \mu, \mathbb{R})$. Hence (iii) holds with $g=|f|$.
>
> "(iii) $\Rightarrow(\mathrm{i})$ " This follows from $f^{+} \vee f^{-} \leq|f| \leq g$ and **Remark 3.3(b)**.

**[Theorem $3.9$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4299760/equivalent-integrability-criteria-f-in-mathcall-1x-mu-e-if-and-onl)** is as follows:

> Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space. For $f \in \mathcal{L}_{0}(X, \mu, E)$, the following are equivalent:
>
> (i) $f \in \mathcal{L}_{1}(X, \mu, E)$;
>
> (ii) $|f| \in \mathcal{L}_{1}(X, \mu, \mathbb{R})$;
>
> (iii) $\int_{X} |f| \mathrm  d \mu<\infty$ in the sense of Lebesgue integral.

Here $\mathcal L_0 (X, \mu, E)$ is the space of all $\mu$-measurable functions and $\mathcal L_1 (X, \mu, E)$ the space o all $\mu$-integrable functions. Related definitions of **Bochner integral** whose related definitions can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space).

---

**My question:** My concern is the proof of "(ii) $\Rightarrow$ (iii)".

- To apply **Theorem 3.9**, $E$ has to be a Banach space. Clearly, the extended real line $\overline{\mathbb{R}} := \mathbb R \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ is a topological space with order topology but not a metric space [[ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1418481/368425)], let alone Banach space. So I feel the use of Theorem 3.9 is not appropriate.
- Also, $f$ possibly takes values $\pm \infty$, so it is not necessarily true that $|f| \in \mathcal{L}_{1}(X, \mu, \mathbb{R})$.

Could you elaborate on my confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(ii) implies that $|f| <\infty$ almost everywhere. Let $f_1(x)=f(x)$ if $f(x) \in \mathbb R$ and $0$ otherwise. Apply Theorem 3.9 (with $E=\mathbb R$)to $f_1$. You get $|f_1| \leq g$ a.e. for some $g \in L^{1}$; the same $g$ works for $f$ too.